# Wired Connection Not Working Ubuntu 16.04 Dual boot with windows 10

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 16.04, internet, wired

I dual booted my computer yesterday. Everything works fine except the internet connection keeps disconnecting. It never actually connects. It goes offline constantly.

Ive read multiple threads and nothing worked. Here is some info -

*ifconfig -a*

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:dd:a9:7e:5e:a8  
      inet6 addr: fe80::b5a8:8559:5f56:d0ff/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7730 (7.7 KB)  TX bytes:69310 (69.3 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7100000-f7120000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:3645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:269510 (269.5 KB)  TX bytes:269510 (269.5 KB)
```

*sudo lshw -c network*

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 05
   serial: 14:dd:a9:7e:5e:a8
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:27 memory:f7100000-f711ffff memory:f7138000-f7138fff ioport:f040(size=32)
```

*cat /etc/network/interfaces*

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1 
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I might want to add that eth0 device does not exist for me.

Edit: changed from eth0 to eno1 in /network/interfaces. Did not fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried getting a new DHCP lease? `sudo dhclient -r eno1` and `sudo dhclient eno1`. And is your wired connection working on windows?

Comment: Yes, it is working on Windows perfectly fine. The problem is only on ubuntu. I havent tried getting a new DHCP.

Comment: I just did. Nothing happened. I should maybe mention that I have 2 different ethernet connections. One Called Wired Connection 1, which is the only one I can use. Second one called "ifupdown (eno1)" which cannot be edited, used or deleted

Comment: to add to @KevInski do `sudo dhclient -vr eno1` and `sudo dhclient -v eno1` give it -v verbose to see what's going on

Comment: Try disabling `fast startup` in `windows`...

Answer (score 0):

The same is happening to me. It's the dual boot with Windows 10. First issue was that the installation did not successfully add a windows 10 to the list so I had to did it after the install by hand with update grub2. And than this .. network eno1 (why renamed from eth0?) first grabbing the wrong ip from the switch and I have probed like

1. disabling ipv6 and then
2. auto reconfiguring file of interfaces to auto on eno1.. it is still failing. On windows 10 everything works DHCP without problems.